# Ti.Network.createHTTPClient

Tags: android, titanium, httpclient, port, appcelerator-mobile

can i create http client in Titanium mobile application which would use port other than 8080?

my code:

```
var clietn = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: function(e){
      ....
      ....
    },
    onerror: function(e){
      ....
      ....
    },

    timeout: 3000
});

client.open("GET", Ti.App.Properties.getString('srvName', '192.168.4.248:8888'));

client.send(JSON.stringify({....}));
```

Doesn't works as I want;

Titanium tells me:

```
[ERROR][TiJSError(  343)] (main) [27918,533680] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime  Error ----
[ERROR][TiJSError(  343)] (main) [0,533680] - In app.js:22,1
[ERROR][TiJSError(  343)] (main) [1,533681] - Message: Uncaught ReferenceError: client is not defined
[ERROR][TiJSError(  343)] (main) [0,533681] - Source: client.open("GET",     Ti.App.Properties.getString('servername', '192.168.4.248:88
[ERROR][V8Exception(  343)] Exception occurred at app.js:22: Uncaught ReferenceError: client is not defined
```

Comment: Look at your code.  You have a typo in your var definition of the client variable.  It is telling you the exact problem, client IS NOT defined.  You defined clietn.  Otherwise, I would guess it should work with alternate ports, probably in exactly the way you are trying it.

Comment: Oh, my God, How can yhis happened to me? THX very much...

Comment: This should just be: Ti.App.Properties.getString('srvName') as well and Ti.App.Properties.setString('srvName', '192.168.4.248:8888'); for setting that variable previously.